# Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/Users/marina/Desktop/PO/angular-po/dist/angular-po/favicon.ico'

Tags: angular, favicon

Running ng build I get an error

Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/Users/marina/Desktop/PO/angular-po/dist/angular-po/favicon.ico'

Do you know how and where to unlink the favicon?

Comment: Need more information on this but for starter try `chown -R marina /Users/marina/Desktop/PO/` command and rebuild project

Answer (score 0):

This favicon errors in angular can be misleading. Usually the real error message is somewhere up in the terminal log.